# How to convert a Gentzen Calculus Formula to a Natural Deduction One

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

I have a proof on my textbook, which prooves denials of quantified propositions ∀xφ ⊨ ¬∃x¬φ... However it is written in Gentzen calculus style, while what I need it a Natural Deduction style one.

[image: Click here to see the proof]

Can you guys tell me what you think about the correction of the proofs in natural deduction?

[image]

Comment: See some textbook: e.f. Negri & von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Structural_Proof_Theory/ZvACGkn9138C)

Comment: In your case is quite simple: 2nd part: assume $\lnot \phi$, use $(\exists \text I)$ and derive a contradiction with the premise. Then use DN.

Comment: Similar for the 1st part, using $(\exists \text E)$ and $(\to \text I)$.

Comment: Thanks, @MauroALLEGRANZA, Can you please tell me in which pages from that book I can find the explanation?

Comment: **Ch.8.2.** Translation from sequent calculus to natural deduction, page172-on.